# Embedding debugging symbols in nuget does not work

Tags: c#, debugging, nuget, symbols, nuget-package

I am making a Nuget package and would like the devs that use it to be able to step through it during debug.

I've heard of "symbol packages" but from the little I know it seems complicated, both for me and for the user, as I would need to setup a symbol package and the user would need to configure a symbol server to use.

I was hoping I can just embed the debug symbols into the package using

```
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
```

in the project file, but when I published a test package with those and downloaded it from Nuget.org on another computer it does not work. The breakpoint I set in the package source is skipped and during debug it says `The breakpoint will not currently be hit. A copy of Class1.cs was found in MyPackage.dll (embedded), but the current source code is different from the version built into MyPackage.dll (embedded)` which I have no idea why comes up.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As often happens, I stumbled upon the answer shortly after posting, which I wish someone would bundle up with `<DebugSymbols>`, as I don't think they work separately.

What I was missing was `<EmbedAllSources>true</EmbedAllSources>`. This embeds the source code in the package and I don't think either of the two options "EmbedAllSources" and "DebugSymbols" works without the other.

It also seems `<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>` is unneeded, as `true` seems to be the default.

Anyone with more information, please feel free to add, correct and etc.

EDIT:

"Release" configuration ignores the "DebugSymbols" directive. So I don't know how you can embed debug symbols in "Release".

Comment: _"So I don't know how you can embed debug symbols in "Release"."_ - use `<DebugType>embedded</DebugType>`